# Is it possible to post data to LinkedIn profile?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I had a look at LinkedIn's API and there are very few POST methods. I was wondering if there is a post method where I can actually edit the details, profile picture, edit intro, edit experience... sections, with my own application.

[image: Only 2??]

If not, I was wondering if this is possible through scraping or any other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit entire profiles, add and remove almost every element but you will need to be part of the LinkedIn Partner program.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1